# Bootstrap 3 - collapsible list not collapsing properly

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3 to make a vertical collapsible nav menu. The docs seem pretty straight forward. Trying to do it using just data-* tags. K.I.S.S.

I can't seem to get the other sections to collapse when I expand a new section. i.e. expanding and collapsing works on each individual item. But the non-active sections are supposed to close automatically if you set a data-parent.

Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pcarroll/b6XCK/2/)

```
    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#one">One</a>
        <ul id="one" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="#">Point One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#two">Two</a>
        <ul id="two" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="#">Point One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ah... The panel classes were the trick... The Javascript must be using them as selectors.

From bootstrap.js: `this.$parent.find('> .panel > .in')`

By adding the panel class to the parent list element, the collapsing now works correctly. Maybe Twitter could have made this feature a but more generic? But it's working now. Hopefully this is not a hack...

Thanks for the clues...

```
<ul id="menu">

    <li class="panel">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#one">One</a>
        <ul id="one" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="#">Point One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="panel">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#two">Two</a>
        <ul id="two" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="#">Point One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li class="panel">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#three">Three</a>
        <ul id="three" class="collapse">
            <li><a href="#">Point One</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Two</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Point Three</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you are using `ul` and `li`. Use as described in the documentation

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/surjithctly/b6XCK/7/)**

HTML

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The collapsible child elements, i.e. the li elements should be wrapped inside a block element having class 'panel'. Simply setting data-parent attribute to #menu won't work. So you need to restructure your HTML.

You can try something like this (styles not fixed to make it look as you did before) -

```
<div id="menu">
  <div class="panel">
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#one">One</a>
      <ul id="one" class="collapse">
          <li><a href="#">Point One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Point Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Point Three</a></li>
      </ul>
    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#menu" href="#two">Two</a>
      <ul id="two" class="collapse">
          <li><a href="#">Point One</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Point Two</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Point Three</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It was the class="panel" missing on the parent element. Doesn't need to be a div. See my answer. Thanks for your help...